# Can I rollout a new release for my Android app programmatically through Android Publisher API?

Tags: python, android, api

So far, my app is still in Internal Testing mode and I was able to upload a new version using Python through this piece of code:

```
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('androidpublisher', 'v3', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)
edit_request = service.edits().insert(body={}, packageName=package_name)
result = edit_request.execute()
edit_id = result['id']

#   Create a request to upload the app bundle
try:
    bundle_response = service.edits().bundles().upload(
        editId=edit_id,
        packageName=package_name,
        media_body=APP_BUNDLE,
        media_mime_type="application/octet-stream"
    ).execute()
except Exception as err:
    message = f"There was an error while uploading a new version of {package_name}"
    raise err

print(f"Version code {bundle_response['versionCode']} has been uploaded")

#   Create a track request to upload the bundle to the beta track
track_response = service.edits().tracks().update(
    editId=edit_id,
    track='internal',
    packageName=package_name,
    body={u'releases': [{
        u'versionCodes': [str(bundle_response['versionCode'])],
        u'status': u'draft',
    }]}
).execute()

print("The bundle has been committed to the internal track")

#   Create a commit request to commit the edit to BETA track
commit_request = service.edits().commit(
    editId=edit_id,
    packageName=package_name
).execute()
```

The problem is when I go to the Google Play console, the new app version is set as "draft" and I have to click through the UI "Edit Release -> Review Release -> Start Rollout to Internal Testing" if I want that version to be published. Is there a way to automate these last few steps? Is this procedure only for Internal Testing apps or do I have to do it too for the production published app?

I understand I am explicitly setting the status as "draft" in the Python script but I wasn't able to find any other status or Android Publisher API call that worked for the upload.